# How to draw specific drawable resource programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have a set of images in my drawable resources. Now I want to be able to change a placeholder image accordingly with `image.setImageResource(R.id.name_of_image)` programmatically.

My ImageView is defined as `ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.placeholder);`

How would I do this? I have tried `getIdentifier` but that didn't work.

The images have the format `Name.jpg`

EDIT:

I currently have the following construction:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(name.toLowerCase(), "drawable", this.getPackageName());
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
image.setImageResource(resID);
```

I have changed the image name to lowercase and it is now a png file.

Comment: How is `image` defined?  Please include the full relevant code.

Comment: edited the post to include the ImageView declaration

Comment: convert `Name.jpg` to `Name.png`.

Comment: Could you explain why this is necessary? Does android not support jpg? This is not a problem but I am curious.

Comment: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html http://android.okhelp.cz/get-resource-id-by-resources-string-name-android-example/ etc

Comment: Why the `.toLowerCase()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images has to be in png format (prefered by android) and must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.].
Then you can use

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.name_of_image);
```

You can get the name of the drawable with this:

```
String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.name_of_image);
```

To get the drawable with the string name:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_image", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: I want name_of_image to be a variable containing the name of the image

Comment: `setImageDrawable` takes `Drawable` as a parameter. not `int`

Comment: OP already said that he is using: `image.setImageResource(R.id.name_of_image)` so what is your answer adding to that?

Comment: He uses a jpg with an invalid name und uses `R.id`.

Comment: @RickTeuthof I edited my answer to get the resources name.

Comment: oh sorry - i missed he uses `R.id`

Comment: I already have the name of the image i want to use stored in a variable, i want to be able to use a construction like `R.drawable.variablename` to show an image depending on the name stored in the variable

Comment: @RickTeuthof use `Resources#getIdentifier` then - there are lots of examples on the web

Comment: I'll edit my post to show what i'm currently trying to do

Comment: @RickTeuthof I added the way you have to go. Maybe you didn't use the `getIdentifier` right.

Comment: Ah i had to edit one minor thing like you posted. Now it works! Thank you very much